# Laravel doesn't return edit view

Tags: php, laravel

im using laravel 5.5 and i created a view for edit categories inside views/back/categories/edit
here my edit function in CategoriesController

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $category = Categories::getall();
        $categories = Categories::find($id);
        return view('back.categories.edit', ['categories' => $categories, 'category' => $category]);
    }
```

and here is my route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'],function(){

    Route::get('/dashboard','BackendController@index')->name('backend');
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories'], function () {
        Route::any('/show/{id}', ['as' => 'backend.categories.show', 'uses' => 'backend\CategoriesController@show']);
        Route::get('/index', ['as' => 'back.categories.index', 'uses' => 'backend\CategoriesController@index']);
        Route::any('/store', ['as' => 'back.categories.store', 'uses' => 'backend\CategoriesController@store']);
        Route::any('/create', ['as' => 'back.categories.create', 'uses' => 'backend\CategoriesController@create']);
        Route::any('/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'back.categories.edit', 'uses' => 'backend\CategoriesController@edit']);
        Route::any('/update', ['as' => 'back.categories.update', 'uses' => 'backend\CategoriesController@update']);
        Route::any('/destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'back.categories.destroy', 'uses' => 'backend\CategoriesController@destroy']);
    });

});
```

my edit button

```
    <a href="{{ url('back/categories/edit/'.$category->cat_id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
<span class="fa fa-edit"></span> edit</a>
```

when i click on the edit button it return page not found with "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." text and the URL :"back/categories/edit/4"

Comment: Do you use `back` prefix for these routes?

Comment: i don't think so my index and create route work but i don't know why my edit route doesn't work with returning the view.I tried to see something wrong with my view but it still work if i put that view in other routes to view, but not the edit route

Comment: Please show an example of a link to the `index` route.

Comment: `url('/back/categories/edit/'.$category->cat_id)`

Comment: @Sohel0415 this will create absolutely the same full URL.

Comment: @o0o0keem try this `{{ url('categories/edit/'.$category->cat_id) }}`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin thanks for noticing Sir, it just a pattern that i used in my project, so thought if it may help. It may be something with `back` prefix i guess though.

Comment: `$category = getall()` and `$categories = find($id)` shouldn't be the opposite ?

Comment: yeah it's wrong i fixed it :) , sorry for my bad english :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your route are named, you can use the [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) helper to build working URL:

```
{{ route('back.categories.edit', ['id' => $category->cat_id]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your routes definition it looks like your url is `/categories/edit/{id}`

For links in templates I suggest to use the `route` helper function which takes the route name or the `action` method which takes `controller@method`

Also have a look at resource controllers

`Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');` could replace your entire routes definition

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `back` portion of the prefix on your `categories` group.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'back/categories'], function () {
```

That would match your routes.